# Getting the name of a child class within the base class constructor

Tags: java

Suppose I have an abstract class

`public abstract class Foo`

and a single constructor

```
public Foo()
{
}
```

Given that this constructor must have been called from the construction of a child class, is there a way of recovering the name of that child class within the `Foo` constructor?

I'd rather not do something evil with the stack trace.

Comment: Without a stacktrace that's quite hard, unless of course you pass it as param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the name of the class like `getClass().getSimpleName()` it suffice to just use

```
public Foo() {
  declaredClassname = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

because of polymorphy it will always call getClass() from the child class.

Comment: Sure it will, I use it all the time

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I use it for couchDb entities where you need a type attribute to be able to select them and I just use that apporach (base class that sets `setDbType(this.getClass().getSimpleName());` in the constructor of the base class (so super constructor for all entities)) although its not abstract, but that shouldnt make a difference

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
public Foo()
{
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course:

```
getClass()
```

But notice that the child class instance (i.e. its fields) still is not initialized, and will be done after the base class constructor. Also do not call overridable methods for the same reason.

Execution of child class constructor:

1. super() or super(...) constructor
2. fields that are initialized `Xxx xxx = ...;`
3. rest of constructor code

Answer (score 0):

You could get it in the subclass constructor and pass it as a String to the super class constructor:

```
public foo(String className)
{
}

//subclass constructor
public subclass()
{
     super("subclass");
}
```

Or you could do:

```
public foo(String className)
{
}

//subclass constructor
public subclass()
{
     super(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Comment: This really not a good solution getClass().getSimpleName() just works as expected with child classes

Comment: It adds complexity when simpler solutions exists

Comment: This is a good solution. The question being asked is that the super class constructor needs the name of the subclass. One small suggestion is to use `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` instead of the string literal `subclass` in the `super` call.

Comment: @brso05 Adding a paramater to a base class is adding complexity no matter how simple it is. Also you need an extra line of code in every child class's constructor. That is why it is a solution, but not a good one.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're in a class hierarchy and you want to know the class that actually is constructed, you can use getClass().
In case you want to know the "topmost" class instead of the "bottommost" class, iterate over the superclasses until before you find your own class.

```
import static java.lang.System.err;
abstract class A {
    protected A() {
        err.format("%s %s%n", getClass().getName(), getTopMostSubclass().getName());
    }
    Class<? extends A> getTopMostSubclass() {
        Class<?> previousClass = getClass(), currentClass;
        while (!A.class.equals(currentClass = previousClass.getSuperclass()))
            previousClass = currentClass;
        return (Class<? extends A>) previousClass;
    }
}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        new B(); // prints B B
        new C(); // prints C B
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the getClass() function on the object for which you want to know the class. So in your case you would do something like this:

```
abstract class ParentClass {
    public ParentClass() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
    }
    public String doSomething() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
}

...
...

ChildClass obj = new ChildClass();// will output  ChildClass
```